# creating a dummy variable based on dates for longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, longitudinal

I have longitudinal patient data in R. I would like to create the new_dummy variable just like I demonstrated in the table below. I would like the dummy_variable value to be 0 if the consultation_date variable is smaller than the registration_date variable and to be 1 if the consultation_date variable is bigger than the registration_date variable.

| patid | consultation_date | registration_date | new_dummy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07/07/2016 | 07/07/2018 | 0 |
| 1 | 07/07/2019 | 07/07/2018 | 1 |
| 2 | 14/08/2016 | 07/09/2016 | 0 |
| 3 | 07/05/2015 | 19/02/2016 | 0 |
| 3 | 02/12/2016 | 19/02/2016 | 1 |

Comment: Try `df1$new_dummy <- with(df1, +(as.Date(consultation_date, "%d/%m/%Y") < as.Date(registration_date, "%d/%m/%Y")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are in the right class (`Date`), you can simply use

```
df$new_dummy <- as.numeric(df$consultation_date < df$registration_date)
```

To convert them in the right format, it's:

```
df$consultation_date <- as.Date(df$consultation_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
df$registration_date <- as.Date(df$registration_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

(thanks @akrun for the date format)